# DOJO gui elements, control the display using backend Authorisation of user

Tags: rest, dojo, html

I have a dojo based gui which gets the data from webservices.

At the tomcat, i already have an existing authorization security server which an provide me certain list functions a user can perform.

How can i enable and disable certain dojo widgets/menus available on my webpage based on the list of functions my server gives for the logged in user?

(As of now, what i can think of is only use a javascript method to enable and disable widgets once all are loaded, list of functions will be passed on the gui thru a REST call. But i feel this is not a good way to do.)

Thanks